# Pytorch Error, RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Double

Tags: python, types, pytorch

I have run into the following error while training a BERT classifier. The

```
type(b_input_mask) = type(b_labels) = torch.Tensor      

type(b_labels[i]) = tensor(1., dtype=torch.float64)

type(b_input_masks[i]) = class'torch.Tensor'
```

What could be the possible data type error here since I have not typecasted any variable to either long or double?

Thanks in advance!
[image: Error Stack Trace]

Answer (score 2):

In a classification task, the data type for input labels should be Long but you assigned them as float64

```
type(b_labels[i]) = tensor(1., dtype=torch.float64)

=>

type(b_labels[i]) = tensor(1., dtype=torch.long)
```

Comment: where should I typecast the float type to long type? In the above-attached image, will labels = np.int_(b_input_mask) will do it for me? Note: np.int_ is for long type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`torch.Tensor.long`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.long) to convert tensor to expected `long` type.

```
# Here, you can pass parameter like this in your call
..., labels = b_labels.long())
```